# Azure Batch and API Job ADD: upload file in wd directory with

Tags: azure-batch, resource-files

I'm using [API Job Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/job/add) to create one Job with one Task in Azure Batch.

This is my test code:

```
{
    "id": "20211029-1540",
    "priority": 0,
    "poolInfo": {
        "poolId": "pool-test"
    },
    "jobManagerTask": {
        "id": "task2",
        "commandLine": "cmd /c dir",
        "resourceFiles": [
            {
                "storageContainerUrl": "https://linkToMyStorage/MyProject/StartTask.txt"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To execute the API I'm using Postman and to monitor the result I'm using BatchExplorer.

The job and it's task are created correctly, but the 'wd' folder generate automatically is empty.
If I understood fine, I should see the linked file in the storage variable, right?
[image]

[image]

Maybe, some other parameter is needed in the Json of the body?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Task state of `completed` does not necessarily indicate success. From your json body, you most likely have an error:

```json
        "resourceFiles": [
            {
                "storageContainerUrl": "https://linkToMyStorage/MyProject/StartTask.txt"
            }
```

You've specified a `storageContainerUrl` with a file. Also ensure you have provided proper permissions (either via SAS or a user managed identity).

Comment: Of course, the link posted is only an example.
So, I don't see any file in wd folder because I don't have the grant?
Without grant I receive this error: "One of the specified Azure Blob container(s) is not found", than I think that the grant are correct, but I don't know if other grant are required.

Comment: You will need to ensure that the URI provided has the proper SAS as required for access or provided via Managed Identity. If you are getting a "not found" error, then you may want to double check that your link is valid and the storage account/container exists.